# Tailwind CSS - How to make content height fit to screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm working on an admin dashboard with tailwind css. I want to make the height of Nav and Content fit to the screen.

I know this will do the trick `relative flex min-h-screen` but by doing so I'm getting the scroll bar because of the height of App Bar.

How can I make the content height 100% without getting the scroll bar?

Minus App Bar height somehow ?

```
<>
  <div className='bg-blue-700 px-8 flex items-center justify-between py-4 shadow-sm text-white'>
    App Bar
  </div>
  <div className='relative flex'>
    <nav className='bg-white shadow-sm p-6 space-y-6 w-64'>
      Navbar
    </nav>
    <main className='bg-gray-100 flex-1 p-6'>
      Content will go here
    </main>
  </div>
</>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put the entire layout in a `min-h-screen flex flex-col` container (or on the body tag), then use `flex-grow` to fill the remaining height below the app bar...

```
<div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
    <div class='bg-blue-700 px-8 flex items-center justify-between py-4 shadow-sm text-white'> App Bar </div>
    <div class='relative flex flex-grow'>
        <nav class='bg-white shadow-sm p-6 space-y-6 w-64'> Navbar </nav>
        <main class='bg-gray-100 flex-1 p-6'> Content will go here </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply demo](https://codeply.com/p/rRnamgJHi6)

Comment: Thanks for your help. can you please share any good resource to learn more about flexbox?

Comment: My favorite is https://flexboxfroggy.com or these [Tailwind layouts using flexbox](https://dev.to/codeply/helpful-page-layouts-using-tailwind-css-1a3k)

Comment: you're a legend, I'll pray to you every night. you are my new God.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for the responsive app :)

Demo [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0odJhP0OUu). :)

```
<div class="flex flex-col w-full min-h-screen overflow-x-hidden">
  <div class="bg-blue-700 px-6 items-center justify-between py-4 shadow-sm text-white">App Bar</div>
  <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row">
     <nav class="w-full sm:w-1/6 bg-white shadow-sm p-6 space-y-6">Navbar</nav>
     <main class="flex bg-gray-100 w-full h-auto p-6">
        Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat.</div>
     </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: thanks for your efforts. by default Navbar is hidden on phones. I've added a menu icon in the app bar for phones. you can toggle the Navbar by clicking it.