# Fit remaining height

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a layout with TailwindCss similar to this:

```
+----------------------+
|                      |
+-----+----------------+
|     |                |
|     |                |
|     |                |
|     |                |
+-----+----------------+
```

This should fit the screen (both width and height). When the screen size changes it should adapt without displaying scrollbars.

So far I came up with this:

```html
<!doctype html>                                                                                               
<html class="h-full">                                                                                         
<head>                                                                                                        
  <meta charset="UTF-8">                                                                                      
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                                      
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>                                                         
</head>                                                                                                       
<body class="h-full">                                                                                         
  <div class="h-full">                                                                                        
    <div class="flex flex-row h-40 bg-red-500">                                                               
    </div>                                                                                                    
    <div class="flex flex-grow">                                                                              
      <div class="flex bg-sky-600 w-48">                                                                      
      </div>                                                                                                  
      <div class="flex flex-grow bg-green-600">                                                               
          <canvas width=100 height=200 style="border: 10px solid black;"></canvas>                            
      </div>                                                                                                  
    </div>                                                                                                    
  </div>                                                                                                      
</body>                                                                                                       
</html>
```

The previous code results in this

[image]

Comment: I belive this is your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68083319/tailwind-css-how-to-make-content-height-fit-to-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed class of first div inside the body from `h-full` to `h-full flex flex-col`

```html
<!doctype html>                                                                                               
<html class="h-full">                                                                                         
<head>                                                                                                        
  <meta charset="UTF-8">                                                                                      
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                                      
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>                                                         
</head>                                                                                                       
<body class="h-full">                                                                                         
  <div class="h-full flex flex-col">                     
    <div class="flex flex-row h-40 bg-red-500">       
    </div>                                                                       
    <div class="flex grow">                                                                              
      <div class="flex bg-sky-600 w-48">     
      </div>                                                                                                  
      <div class="flex flex-grow bg-green-600">                                                               
          <canvas width=100 height=200 style="border: 10px solid black;"></canvas>                            
      </div>                                                                                                  
    </div>     
  </div>                                                                                                      
</body>                                                                                                       
</html>
```